# Не убирается событие.ТоТ

Tags: javascript

Я знаю, что очень сильно туплю.

```
 <html>
<head>
<script>
var x=0;
function light(){
x++;
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].style.opacity=x/100;
document.body.innerHTML+=x;
if(x<100){setTimeout(light,1000);}
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background-image: url('grey.png'); background-repeat: no-repeat;">
<img src='gold.png' onclick="this.onclick=null;light();" style='opacity: 0;'>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Пытаюсь написать скрипт, чтобы при нажатии на картинку плавно менялось её значение opacity. Проблема в том, что при повторном нажатии она запускается ещё раз, что не желательно. надо бы убрать эту функцию после первого нажатия. вот так не помогает..  onclick="this.onclick=null;light();" в чём я дурак?

Comment: <img src='gold.png' onclick="this.onclick=null;alert('FUCK!')" style='opacity: 0;'>  
так при втором клике алерт не выскакивает  
<img src='gold.png' onclick="this.onclick=null;alert('FUCK!'); light()" style='opacity: 0;'>  
а так выскакивает, и функция тоже запускается.

Comment: @Dazar а вот мат на [Хэшкод](http://hashcode.ru/ "Форум программистов")е запрещён! :)

Comment: А это не мат, это моё личное тестовое слово, которое я использую для отладки, когда долго ничего не получается. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну, скажу честно, мне не нравится ваша реализация с работой `opacity` :)

В общем вот, держите. Я бы так сделал:

http://jsfiddle.net/cjXwc/1/

```
<script>
function light(obj){
    alert('start');

    var firstImage = obj.style;

    var interval = setInterval(function() {

        if(firstImage.opacity >= 1) {
            clearInterval(interval);
            return;
        }

        firstImage.opacity = parseFloat(firstImage.opacity) + .1;

    }, 100);

    obj.removeAttribute('onclick');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div style="background: gray">
<img src='http://hashcode.ru/upfiles/logo.png' onclick="light(this);" style='opacity: 0;'>
</div>
```

Comment: В общем:
Ответ принимаю, this.removeAttribute('onclick'); своё дело сделал.
В вашем коде с радостью покопаюсь, полезно будет.

Comment: @Dazar пожалуйста!

Comment: Кстати вот результат, раз уж сделал, можно и залить..   http://www.dazar.16mb.com/